# Horizontal lines

Tags: header-footer

[image]In my header of a page in documentclass scrbook there should be two horizontal lines with text in between.

This was my idea:

```
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
{\color{black}\rule{12cm}{0.7mm}}
\begin{center}
{\Large\textbf{Musterklausur Nr. 1}\\[3mm]
\textbf{Lösungsvorschlag}}
\end{center}
{\color{black}\rule{12cm}{0.7mm}}
\end{minipage}
```

Before i have made a pagebreak. My problem ist that the folowing text has no distance to the lower line. When I put a \vspace*{4mm} in the text goes down till the half of the page.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example code that reproduces the problem. Without this it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: You should configure things so that e.g. `\maketitle` does the formatting rather than marking it up manually. But, as already pointed out, it is difficult to advise how best to do that without a Minimum Working Example.

Answer (score 3):

This solution provides two ways -- first with a tabular environment and second with an adjustable `tcolorbox` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{colortbl}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}%

\newcounter{musterklausur}

\newlength{\kopfbreite}
\setlength{\kopfbreite}{0.9\textwidth}%
\newlength{\liniendicke}
\setlength{\liniendicke}{0.7mm}%

\newcommand{\musterklausurkopf}{%
\stepcounter{musterklausur}%
\begin{center}
\arrayrulecolor{black}%
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\liniendicke}%
\begin{tabular}{p{\kopfbreite}}
\hline 
\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\Large \textbf{Musterklausur Nr. \themusterklausur}}\tabularnewline %\[3mm]
\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\Large \textbf{Lösungsvorschlag}}\tabularnewline
\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}%
}%


\newcommand{\musterklausurkopfalternativ}{%
\stepcounter{musterklausur}%
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\kopfbreite,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,boxsep=0.3cm,toprule=0.7mm,leftrule=0pt,bottomrule=0.7mm,rightrule=0pt,colframe=blue]
\begin{center}
\Large \textbf{Musterklausur Nr. \themusterklausur}\par
\vspace{\baselineskip}%
\Large \textbf{Lösungsvorschlag}
\end{center}
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{center}
}%



\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No indentation

\begin{document}
\musterklausurkopf%


Aufgabe 1 % Use a problem/answer package for this!)

\blindtext

\newpage

\musterklausurkopfalternativ%


Aufgabe 2 % Use a problem/answer package for this!)

\blindtext



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}     
\noindent\begin{minipage}{12cm}
\rule{12cm}{0.7mm}
    \begin{center}
\textbf{Musterklausur Nr. 1}\\[3mm]
\textbf{Lösungsvorschlag}
    \end{center}
\rule{12cm}{0.7mm}\par
\vspace*{1ex}% or desired distance
        \end{minipage}
Aufgabe 1% this line also can be put after \vspace* command
    \end{document}
```